# how to handle catch in sinon, unit testing nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sequelize.js, sinon-chai

in my UserService:

```
createUser: async (data) => {
    const user = new UserDBEntryMapper(data);
    const createdUser = await UserModel.create(user).catch(error => {
      this.handleError(error);
    });
    return createdUser ? new UserBOMapper(createdUser) : null;
  }
```

in my user.test.js

```
it.only('Create New User', async () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(UserModel, "create").returns(user);
    const created = await UserService.createUser(user);
    expect(stub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
});
```

throwing the error as:

```
Create New User:
TypeError: UserModel.create(...).catch is not a function
```

If I remove `catch` block in `UserService` the test passes, but we need a catch block there. How do I handle this?

**Note:** `UserModel.create()` is `sequelize` default function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise needs to be returned in a mock. Something like this

```
const stub = sinon.stub(UserModel, "create").returns(Promise.resolve(user));
```

Comment: It didn't work. also updated the snippet, i am handling the error in separate function below.